# String.Replace doesn't appear to be replacing Hex char

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a class decorated with XML attributes such as [XmlAttribute("att")]. My goal is to create an XDocument with this class's xml. Everything works great except for a '0x1f' character that occasionally enters the scene externally. So naturally I try to replace it like so:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(sw, this);
string s = sw.ToString();
s = s.Replace((char)0x1F, ' ');
XDocument xs = XDocument.Parse(s);
return xs;
```

However I still get an error: "' ', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character."

Just for a sanity check, here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIos4.png

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Comment: And try to find how `'0x1f' character occasionally enters the scene externally`

Comment: @L.B, these strings with 0x1f are retrieved from a web service call that's not my code (i.e. external to my code base). Even if I string.replace the offending character hot off the service call, it still seems to persist!

Comment: @L.B, Thanks for the link. I will be sure that an accepted answer gets marked. I only have internet access via a tiny mobile screen so my breach of convention wasn't immediately obvious to me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the same response if it's represented as an entity - maybe that's what's happening? Look at `s` to be sure.

Sample:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<foo>&#31;</foo>";
        XDocument.Parse(xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your suggestion to add this line: s.Replace("&#31;", string.Empty);

Unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: @b9190db9: Well my first suggestion is to *look at that string*. Put a breakpoint in the debugger, or log it somewhere - whatever it takes to look at it closely. Find out what form the bad character is taking...

Comment: I can set a conditional breakpoint where I'm looking for "0x1F", and the program successfully breaks. Then I call string.replace as I wrote above, and set another conditional breakpoint which also breaks. Copy/Pasting the string to something like Notepad++ doesn't show the character as I'd expect. I'm having trouble sifting thought this strangeness :P

Comment: @b9190db9: It shows you the line and position number in the exception, which should help...

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. I'm able to grab the offending, invisible character, but I'm not successful in replacing it. I'll copy paste the code here, it doesn't take up any pixels when printed, but Visual Studio knows it's there. Hopefully StackOverflow's comment system retains it:  char badChar = '';

Comment: @b9190db9: If you can find the index within the string, see what the exact Unicode value is. I know the exception is *claiming* it's U+001F, but I'm beginning to wonder...

Comment: Shoot, it looks like it's filtered out by SO. Pasting it back into VS has no char at all. I'll try to think of another way to post the char for others

Comment: @b9190db9: Can you put the whole document/file up somewhere, or is it confidential?

Comment: The document is confidential, but your suggestion to find the index, specifically iterating over the string.ToCharArray() shows a char value of 31. Also, pastebin will accept my strange character: http://pastebin.com/tpq9hbMk If you copy paste that into VS or something like notepad++, you'll see the offender

Comment: @b9190db9: What are the characters each side of it? I'd *really* have expected `Replace` to work...

Comment: Based on the string index given by the exception text, I set a char variable (named offender) to that element in the string array. From the VS debugger: offender = 32 ' '. The values on either side of that element are also 32. However when I copy paste the value to Notepad++ and back to vs, it appears to be char value 31.

Comment: @b9190db9. What does `s.IndexOf('\u001f')` in a watch window show? (We'll get there...)

Comment: @b9190db9: Okay, tallies with `Replace` not replacing it. Hmm. How are you cutting and pasting it to Notepad++ and back? (Where are getting it from to copy?)

Comment: If I mouseover the variable when the program is in a Break state, a popup shows the variable name and value. If I right click on it, I can Copy, Copy Value, etc. Doing this and pasting it into N++ will work. Thanks again for the help, Jon, I have to commute home so I'll check back here later in the weekend and/or monday. I can't thank you enough for sticking with me!!

Comment: One strange thing is that if I set a breakpoint with the condition s.Contains((char)0x1F), I get a break. However if I enter the same condition in the watch window, the result is false! What is this wizardry!

Comment: It's strange but it's repeatable. I'm accepting this answer because it ultimately led to my solution, which is to call HTTPEncode on the string first, then call string.replace for the offending character. Of note is that VS will still not detect the character in the watch window, neither before nor after I call HTTPEncode. I realize this makes no sense. I want to thank you for all the help, Jon! I was never handy with the watch window before but now I feel like a pro :D

Comment: @b9190db9: If you ever get to the stage where you've got a non-confidential file you can repeat this with, do feel free to ping me an email. Would enjoy looking at it.

Comment: I just added an answer that might be of interest

Answer (score 2):

The character x1F is not legal in XML 1.0. So XML parsers will reject it. It's legal in XML 1.1 provided it is written in escaped form a `&#x1f;` - but not everyone supports XML 1.1. Best thing is to work out where this character is entering the system and stop it happening at source.

Answer (score 1):

For me there were some issues if you try to replace using the string instead of the char. I suggest trying some testing values using both to see what they turn up. Also how you reference it has some effect.

```
var a = x.IndexOf('\u001f');                      // 513
var b = x.IndexOf(Convert.ToString((byte)0x1F));  // -1
x = x.Replace(Convert.ToChar((byte)0x1F), ' ');   // Works
x = x.Replace(Convert.ToString((byte)0x1F), " "); // Fails
```

[I blagged this](http://nenotlep.blogspot.fi/2012/12/0x1f.html)